# Error 12175 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR A security error occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have created website in asp.net core 2.1. In this website we are calling third party HTTPS webapi using httpclient. My website is working fine when i deployed on Smarterasp.net shared hosting server but when i deployed on windows 2016 server with proxy settings it is giving following error. This only happened for HTTPS APi. For Non-https api it is working fine on windows server 2016.

Login Failed Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12175 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A security error occurred'.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequest(WinHttpRequestState state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

I have done some research and based on that I have set following code but still getting above error. Working fine for Non-Https api.

```
 AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
         if (ProxySettings.Current.UseProxy)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };

            var proxy = new WebProxy();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxySettings.Current.ProxyHost) && ProxySettings.Current.ProxyPort != 0)
            {
                proxy = new WebProxy(ProxySettings.Current.ProxyHost, ProxySettings.Current.ProxyPort);
            }
            proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = ProxySettings.Current.UseDefaultCredentials;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxySettings.Current.ProxyUrl))
                proxy.Address = new Uri(ProxySettings.Current.ProxyUrl);

            if (ProxySettings.Current.HasNetworkCredentials)
            {
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                credentials.UserName = ProxySettings.Current.NetworkUserName;
                credentials.Password = ProxySettings.Current.NetworkPassword;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxySettings.Current.NetworkDomain)) credentials.Domain = ProxySettings.Current.NetworkDomain;

                proxy.Credentials = credentials;
            }

            handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = true,
                Proxy = proxy,
            };
        }
```

Can you please help to get solution?

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: I had the same problem and had to switch back to .net 4.6.1 to get it to work... :(

Comment: Hi, same here, https connexion randomly fail on .net core (2.0 => 5.0), but work fine in .net framework.
I got a different message when not disabling SocketsHttpHandler, but anyway, doesn't work.